# Make tags on pins with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, tags

I'm making a website, where I want to be able to make tags on pictures on the pins like on Facebook. Instead of tagging friends/people that you do on Facebook, than I want tags with a text on the pictures.

Like want it to be like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Falcv.png]

The drawn line shows that when you hold your pad on the tag than it should show where the tag is on the picture. 
I also want when you go through the picture with the pad to show the tags a it's place on the picture like on Facebook.

I'm using devise to make the pins.

I hope that someone can help me with this, because that could be really sweet.

Answer (score 0):

**Devise**

Okay, firstly, **you can't use `devise` to make the pins**

`Devise` is an [authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) system - it allows your users to register / login, that's it. You'll have to create another model called `Pin` to make this happen most likely -

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :pins
end

#app/models/pin.rb
Class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

--

**Pins**

Using a separate `pin` model means you'll be able to create / load the pins resource itself, which will either mean using the [`nested_model`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) structure, or just directly referencing the `pins` resource